# installing a new package in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: apt, package-management

I have a problem with installing a new package in Ubuntu, I want to install library `pcrafter`, and I have downloaded the files from [here](https://code.google.com/p/libcrafter/downloads/list) (crafter-0.2.tar.gz) but when I use this command "
 `sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8 libpcap0.8-dev` 
Ubuntu gives me this error:

```
E: Couldn't find package libpcap0.8-dev
```

now I don't know what should I do? where is the problem?
and I have another question too, I want to use MPI in my program to make it parallel, can I do this with programming in Ubuntu? I mean is it possible?

Comment: You've downloaded sources, you have to build them and install without using apt-get, run something like `./configure && make && make install` (its not all-purpose line it depends)

Comment: there is a `README` and `INSTALL` file in the the archive.

Comment: @ prajmus when I use the ./configure command it says:                  configure: error: libpcap not found

Comment: sorry, I haven't read the `README` file earlier. There are actually packages in Ubuntu that need to be installed before `./configure`. What's your Ubuntu version ? I have `libpcap0.8-dev` available to install

Comment: @itwasntpete yes, you are right...so what should I do after that? should i delete them? there is three file named INSTALL,README,and install-sh files in my folder, which one should I delete?

Comment: @user3201263 Not delete, read, README file as the name says wants to be read

Comment: @user3201263 For your extra question, MPI is available in almost all Linux distros, including Ubuntu. Install `openmpi` or any MPI packages you wants using `apt-get`.

Comment: in the read me file  has been written "Before configuring and compiling libcrafter you need lipcap an libnet installed in your system. On debian based distros, you should execute:"                            that apt-get install libnet1 libnet1-dev libpcap0.8 libpcap0.8-dev       but when I executed it, it says me "E: Couldn't find package libnet1
"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu administration.

Comment: @JohnDibling it is about the programming and installing a new library for c++ progtamming in ubuntu, so I don't see any problem with answring it here!!!!

Comment: @user3201263:  You actually have asked two completely unrelated questions here.  One is about installing a package in Ubuntu.  Whether or not you intend to use that package for programming is irrelevant.  Since the title of this message pertains to that question, that is what this question is about.  The second question MPI programming.  The fact that it is in Ubuntu is irrelevant.  It needs to be a question of it's own, as we can't really deal well with single posts that include multiple questions.

Comment: **However** the second question as you have it here would be downvoted an closed, because it's far too vague.  General, forum-type questions like "is X possible" are off-topic on all SE sites.  You would be better served by doing your own research. SE is for specific, answerable questions.  Not general, wide-ranging questions that would lead to long discussions.

Comment: SE isn't an internet forum.  It's a Question & Answer site.  the questions are expected to be specific, and the hope is that the answers are excellent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try?

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Also you can download the .deb file for libpcap0.8-dev [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libpcap0.8-dev/download).

Once you download that file you can run this command

```
dpkg -i libpcap0.8-dev_1.1.1-10_amd64.deb
```

Comment: thank you, but after executing the dpkg -i libpcap0.8-dev_1.1.1-10_amd64.deb command it says:  package architecture (amd64) does not match system (i386),what shuold I do?where is the problem?

Comment: @user3201263 Sorry, I should have anticipated that. Download [this one instead](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/libpcap0.8-dev/download) and run this command:
`dpkg -i libpcap0.8-dev_1.1.1-10_i386.deb`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly unpack it:

```
tar zxf crafter-0.2.tar.gz
```

then cd in the directory:

```
cd crafter-0.2
```

then you might need to configure it:

```
./configure && make
```

then

```
sudo make install
```

This is one of the more "standard" ways to install software on linux by compilation.

Update: `sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev` might be needed according to your comment

Comment: This question was off-topic.  Pardon me for saying so, but by answering it you are encouraging others to ask off-topic questions in the future.